Getting error when call api in react on a site deployed in Azure?
I have a react jsx file that makes a call to a service as follows and the code in the service is as follows:
         const copydata = (id, name) => {
         return data_post('acmeAdmin/CopyData', { id: id, name: name })
        }

Then I have a c# controller which has the following :
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("CopyData")]
    public JsonResult CopyData([FromBody] CopyDataModel model)
    {
        var copydata = new helper.CopyData(model.id, model.name, out string error, out 
        string newid, _logger);            
        return new JsonResult(new { copydata = copydata, error = error, newid = newid });
    }


public class CopyDataModel
{        
    public string id { get; set; }    
    public string name { get; set; }        
}

The issue is that it all works when i run locally , but when i deploy to Azure and try to run it , it gives the error:
       https://<my_react_app>/acmeAdmin/CopyData  (Not Allowed)

or Bad Request?
Now this routine copies data between regions and i have setup CORAS in the deployed react app.
Any reason why these errors happen and how can i resolve ?
